# Terminal showing environment variables on startup

Tags: macos, terminal, environment-variables, iterm2

Since today my terminal shows all kind of variables on startup.

[image: Text]

This is my ~/.zshrc file:

[image: Text]

I don't think something bad will come of it but I'm just wondering how this happened and how I can turn it back off.

Thankyou for your help!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`export` is called as a command, and shows all the exported vars.

---

You should make the

```
export
JAVA_HOME=...
```

A single line, so `export` isn't called without args:

```
export JAVA_HOME= ...
```